# reading namespaced attributes with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Given a document like this:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="de">
<body>
    ...
</body>
```

How can I read the `xml:lang` attribute using jquery?  I can query for elements that have `xml:lang` like this:

```
$('[xml\\:lang]')
```

but I don't know how to get the attribute itself.  `attr('lang')` and `attr('xml\\:lang')` don't work.  I've a jsfiddle showing this [here](http://jsfiddle.net/paleozogt/HRL7E/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`:` has only to be escaped in selectors, since they indicate the start of pseudo selectors. As attribute name you don't have to escape it:

```
.attr('xml:lang')
```

[works fine](http://jsfiddle.net/HRL7E/1/).

Comment: And select html `var lang= $('html').attr('xml:lang');`